# ImportXML Help in Google Sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets

I am working with google sheets and am having some trouble with the importxml function.

I am trying to export the "Beypoints" score from both battle data sections, but cannot get it to cooperate.

Source code: view-source:https://worldbeyblade.org/User-Bey-Brad

Comment: You should show the formula that you tried and if you got an error you should include it. Please checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind trying another way, try the following.

```
=index(importhtml("https://worldbeyblade.org/User-Bey-Brad","table",7),2,2)
```

and

```
=index(importhtml("https://worldbeyblade.org/User-Bey-Brad","table",8),2,2)
```